# Deploying an RShiny Application online, with access to a Database

Tags: mysql, r, database, hosting

As the Title already says, I'am trying to deploy an RShiny Application but can't get it to work because it needs access to a Database. Either the Webhosters I've found don't allow installing Rstudio Server or I can't access a Database remotely, are there any alternative methods I could use to host the App as well as my Database?

Thank you in advance

Comment: Do you need to have the database and app on the same server?  That's likely to be expensive.  And complicated.  My own solution has been to host the app on shinyapps.io and the database on AWS.  I've had to create an API on AWS to handle the communication between app and database, but that's not too difficult and is likely to be required in any situation where app and database are hosted separately.  DB hosts generally don't allow remote access.  I can't host the database on shinyapps.io because shinyapps.io is containerised.

Comment: Thank you for your help,  Why do you need to create an API, and can't just access the Database remotely?

Comment: do you really need a relational database, or could a XML file do? shinyapps.io tends to have terrible performance anyway

Comment: Maybe an XML file would work, but how can I access an XML file in R?

Comment: Most (all?) hosts who provide databases block remote access for security reasons.  Quite rightly, in my opinion.  Therefore your app sends requests to the API, the API processes the requests and returns the result, the app handles the result.

Comment: @Johann unless the database is static (ie lookup only) even an XML file won't work on shinyapps.io.  shinyapps.io is containerised, so any changes made by a user are available only to that user for the duration of that particular session.  Everything not deployed with the app is deleted when that particular instance of the app is shut down.

Comment: @Limey you sure? I made an experiment that saved results of various participants on a text file. But that was many years ago and things may have changed.

Comment: @Johann: Yes.  I'm developing an app on shinyapps.io at the moment and have had to move from data storage in local .Rds files to a remote MySQL database hosted on AWS for exactly this reason.  But the MySQL db does bring other benefits (audit trails, access conflict resolution etc), so it's not all pain.

Answer (score 0):

If performance is not mission critical (in which case shiny apps wouldn't be a good choice anyway), and if the database is needed for simple storage of information and no complex database functions are needed, a solution could be using a XML dataset, hosted on dropbox.

An XML file is basically a text file, where you can define "objects" or nodes that have various "values".
you can take a look [here](https://www.w3.org/XML/RDB.html) and [here](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/xml/xml_databases.htm)
for a gentle introduction.

XML can easily be manipulated in R through packages such as xml2. See the [homepage](https://xml2.r-lib.org/) and a [tutorial](https://lecy.github.io/Open-Data-for-Nonprofit-Research/Quick_Guide_to_XML_in_R.html)

Finally as @Limey noted, it is possible that hosts such as shinyapps.io don't allow for permanent storage (i.e. read and write a text file, without it getting deleted every time the app starts).

Various workarounds are offered by the shinyapps.io documentation, here: https://shiny.rstudio.com/articles/persistent-data-storage.html

The easiest/cheapest of which would seem the dropbox implementation, using the [rdrop2 package](https://github.com/karthik/rdrop2). So basically you would have a database.xml text file on a dropbox account which gets read, modified and saved by the app.
Please note that if you expect many concurrent users this solution might not be robust enough out of the box (e.g. what happens if two users simultaneously save?). Still it is a quick and viable option for most educational, and hobby projects.